# Filtering User table by MembershipUserCollection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

So, I have ASP Membership set up in my application. I also have a separate User table for managing non-membership related data.  During user management I need to make sure that my application queries both tables. I have the below Controller that returns a list of approved users, but it seems like there has to be a simpler way to accomplish this. What is a better way to do it?

```
        QuoteExchangeDB _db = new QuoteExchangeDB();

        [MyAuthorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
        public ActionResult Admin()
        {
            MembershipUserCollection agents = Membership.GetAllUsers();
            IEnumerable<MembershipUser> unfiltered = agents.Cast<MembershipUser>();
            var filtered = unfiltered.Where(u => u.IsApproved);
            List<User> users = new List<User>();
            foreach (var item in filtered)
            {
                if (item.IsApproved)
                {
                    Guid guid = (Guid)item.ProviderUserKey;
                    users.Add(_db.Users.Single(u => u.MembershipGuid.Equals(guid)));
                }
            }
            return View(users);
        }
```

Comment: Your `if (item.IsApproved)` block seems redundant, given you're filtering for that already.

Comment: Lol...I did the if statement before I added the Linq statement...I didn't even catch that. Fixing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like you probably want a simple join in LINQ.

```
var filtered = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>().Where(u => u.IsApproved);

var users = from f in filtered
        join u in _db.Users on ((Guid)f.ProviderUserKey) equals u.MembershipGuid
        select u;
```

You could probably make one statement out of that even:

```
var users = from f in Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>()
    join u in _db.Users on ((Guid)f.ProviderUserKey) equals u.MembershipGuid
    where f.IsApproved
    select u;
```

Edit:  Given that I'm not sure how joining an IEnumerable with an IQueryable might affect things/cause problems in this instance, [here's a blog about doing that](http://blog.hompus.nl/2010/08/26/joining-an-iqueryable-with-an-ienumerable/).

Comment: As soon as I get into the office tomorrow morning, I'm going to try this! Excellent approach.